# How order status was chaged in woocommerce after PayPal EC Payment Finished?

Tags: paypal, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox

I am using PayPal Express checkout using WooCommerce I send the information to PayPal from my checkout page and after return to My Site after Payment was completed. I don't know how was my order status is change pending to processing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has nothing to do with programming

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Woo's Plugin you have to define an IPN for the orders to update automatically. Here's some info to help.

You can do one or the other here.

1. Use AngellEye's [Plugin for IPN](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-ipn/)

OR

2. [Walkthrough](https://www.angelleye.com/automatically-update-woocommerce-order-status-when-paypal-payment-completes/) in setting it up manually for WooCommerce

View this guide as it is very thorough using AngellEye

Hope this helps 8^)

Answer (score 0):

To integrate PayPal Express Checkout, 2 best plugins to use are

1. PayPal for WooCommerce by Angell EYE
2. WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Gateway by WooCommerce

NOTE: Before these plugins are installed, make sure that you have backup of your website so if these plugins cause any issues on the website/ crash the website, we still have a backup.

This will take care of the order status when the order is placed.

Above plugins are reliable and used by most of the Merchants on their website.